# Are there any banks in Europe that I can have an account without being in that country?

Tags: bank-account

I am a non EU citizen who does some freelance work to companies in Europe over the Internet. I want to have an account in Europe so that I can keep my payment in Europe as well. (Switzerland or Germany are my first two preferences.) Is it possible?

Later I will need to transfer the money to my own country.

Comment: @Knuckle-Dragger What is a foreign business entity?

Comment: I am doubtful if any bank will allow you to do that, considering the tightening on money laundering in all countries. Why don't you transfer the money directly into your account, rather than inserting another step in the process.

Comment: Do you mean “without being in that country” as in doing everything remotely and never ever visiting it or as in not being a resident?

Comment: @Annoyed never being there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done, but I believe it would be impractical for most people - i.e., it would likely be cheaper to fly to Europe from other side of the world to handle it in person if you can.

It also depends on where you live. You should take a look if there are any branches or subsidiaries of foreign banks in your country - the large multinational banks most likely can open you an account in their sister-bank in another country for, say, a couple hundred euro in fees.

Answer (score 4):

Opening account in foreign bank is possible, but you must have strong proofs you use it for legitimate purposes. More chances to get an account if you visit Europe and able to stay, for example, for a week, to visit bank in person and wait for all the checks and approvals. Also keep in mind that there will be deposit/withdraw limits and fees applicable, that are significantly stricter and larger for non-EU citizen.

In my opinion, if your amounts are not large, it might not worth it. If amounts are large, you might consider business account rather than personal, as is the example of strong proof I meant.